# Disable text box for few seconds after success message

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery

I'm trying to disable a textbox/and button for few seconds after the "Send button" has been clicked and then enable it again as well empty the textbox. But it doesn't work out.

I have an `onSuccess()` function in JavaScipt in combination with using the REST API:

```
function onSuccess(data, request) {
    $("#articleData").html("<span class='red'>Message sent </span>");
    if ($("#articleData").val().length > 0) {
        $("#articleData").val("");
    }
    $("#articleData").empty();
    disable();
}

function disable() {
    x = document.getElementById("savebutton");
    x.disabled=true;
    setTimeout(enable, 3000);
}

function enable() {
    x.disabled=false;
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
function disable(){
    $("#savebutton").prop("disabled", true);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#savebutton").prop("disabled", false);
  }, 3000);
}
```

using javascript:

```
function disable(){
  document.getElementById("savebutton").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("savebutton").disabled = false;
  }, 3000);
}
```